# About the transitivility of the action of $SO(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, group-actions

Let $E^2$ be a two dimensional real vector-space and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ an inner product on $E^2$. If $\mu:SO(2)\times E^2\to E^2$ is the action of the lie group $SO(2)$ over $E^2$, can we deduce the following statement?

> Given $u,v\in E^2$, $||u||=||v||$ there exists $A\in SO(2)$ such that $\mu_A(u)=v$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just take the rotation matrix for angle $\varphi=\mbox{arg}(v)-\mbox{arg}(u)$.

Comment: Thanks! But $\text{arg}(u)$ is the angle of $u$ respect ..... (?)

Comment: @FUUNK1000 It's the angle between $u$ and the positive real axis. You can think about $E^2$ as a complex plane. Then this is an argument of a complex number, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)

Comment: The good thing about rotations is that if $A$ is a rotation by $\varphi$ then $\mbox{arg}(Au)=\mbox{arg}(u)+\phi$. On the other hand every nonzero vector is uniquely determined by its norm and argument. And since rotations preserve norms then there's your answer.

Comment: Of course this is all under the assumption that we talk about the standard action of $2\times 2$ matrices on $E^2$, i.e. the simple matrix-vector multiplication $\mu_A(u):=Au$. After all you said **the** action. For other actions (e.g. the trivial one, where $SO(2)$ doesn't move anything) this obviously does not have to be true.